# Factory instance has no attribute 'startedConnecting'

Tags: python, twisted

I've looked around quite a bit, but haven't found an error quite like this. When I execute my code (below), I get the exception `ControllerFactory instance has no attribute 'startedConnecting'`. I tried adding the method with the body just being `pass`, but that simply causes it to stall without transmitting anything, leading me to believe that the problem lies within the way I've set up the classes.

This code is based on code from the twisted website. It's meant to be able to transmit python files, which the server saves, then later transmit arguments for running the python file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                                        
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
import argparse

file_header = "pfile:"
run_header = "runwith:"

class Controller(protocol.Protocol):
    def sendMessage(self,message):
        self.transport.write(message)


class ControllerFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        cont = Controller()
        cont.factory = self
        return cont


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--address")
    parser.add_argument("--file")
    parser.add_argument("--args")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if(args.file and args.args):
        raise Exception("Can't send file and args at same time.")
    reactor.connectTCP(args.address, 1337, ControllerFactory())
    reactor.run()
    if(args.file):
        print(args.file)
        a = open(args.file)
        factory.connectedProtocol.sendMessage(file_header + a.read())
        a.close()
    if(args.args):
        print(args.args)
        factory.connectedProtocol.sendMessage(run_header + args.args)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory` for clients (instead of `twisted.internet.protocol.Factory`).  Or use something from `twisted.internet.endpoints` instead of `twisted.internet.reactor.connectTCP`.

Also, note that `reactor.run()` blocks.  All of your code that follows that line will not run in any useful way.

Comment: Note that you should only use `ClientFactory` for clients using `connectTCP`.  Clients using endpoints *should* use regular `Factory` objects.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Since reactor.run() blocks, how would I go about sending the data?

Comment: Put the code somewhere it will run. ;)  For example, in an event handler.  The protocol's `connectionMade` method is one possibility.  If you switch to using endpoints then you'll get a `Deferred` representing connection success.  Then you could put the code in a callback attached to that `Deferred` (this would be my preferred appraoch because it leaves your protocol more general and re-usable and puts your application code where it belongs - in your application).

Comment: I added it to the connectionMade function, but that doesn't seem to get called when the connection happens for some reason. The connectionMade on the server triggers properly when the two connect, but not this one.

Comment: `connectionMade` *does* get called when the connection happens.  That is exactly the definition of when it happens.  Something else is confusing you.

Comment: I changed the body of connectionMade to solely print("Connection Made."). The body of main is     print("Connecting to " + args.address)
    reactor.connectTCP(args.address, 1337, ControllerFactory())
    print("Connected.")
    reactor.run(), but this doesn't seem to work, as connectionMade never triggers in this code.

Comment: `connectionMade` is called in all of the many thousands of Twisted-based programs I've written.  It's also called in the unit tests that part of Twisted itself that were written to make sure that it is called when it is supposed to be called.  So I can't guess why it's not called in your program.  Perhaps you could share your program (likely in a new question as this has nothing to do with the `startedConnecting` method this question is about) - complete and self-contained - and someone can see what's wrong with it.